# Acentos gráficos sobre las palabras de una sola silaba

Tags: acentuación

Entiendo las reglas del acento tónico cuando está o no está sobre una sílaba... depende de la última sílaba.

Pero me parece muy extraño cuando este acento gráfico está sobre palabras que tienen solamente una sílaba.

Por ejemplo: la voz (sin acento); más (con acento); él (con acento); el (sin acento); yo (sin acento); vos/nos (sin acento); no, se, un, de...

¿Podríais explicarme, o darme referencias para que no me equivoque?

Comment: Y también hay los que cambiaron como fué/fue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sencillamente, ese acento aparece en palabras con más de una definición para diferenciar entre las dos (o más!) posibles definiciones.  Los ejemplos incluyen:

1. Sí (yes), si (if)
2. Él (he), el (the)
3. Tú (you), tu (your)
4. De (of), dé (subjunctive form of dar, to give)

Cuando se trata de una palabra de una sola sílaba, estos diacríticos no representan ningún cambio ni diferencia en pronunciación en el idioma hablado.

Comment: "estos diacríticos no representan ningún cambio ni diferencia en pronunciación en el idioma hablado" falso.  Las formas sin tilde carecen de acento prosódico y se adjuntan en la pronunciación a la palabra tónica que les sigue.

Answer (score 2):

Mira el punto 3, "tilde diacrítica", en el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas, [aquí](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=tilde).